# How exactly does the caller see a change in the object?

Tags: python, function, object

From [Chapter "Classes"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) of the official Python tutorial:

> [...] if a function modifies an object passed as an argument, the caller will see the change — this eliminates the need for two different argument passing mechanisms as in Pascal.

What would be an example of how exactly the caller will see a change? Or how could it be (not in Python but in general) that the caller doesn't see the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that if a mutable object is changed, it will change everywhere.

For an example of passing by reference (which is what Python does):

```
x = []
def foo_adder(y):
    y.append('foo')
foo_addr(x)
print(x)  # ['foo']
```

vs something like Pascal, where you can pass copies of an object as a parameter, instead of the object itself:

```
# Pretend this is Pascal code.
x = []
def foo_adder(y):
    y.append('foo')
foo_adder(x)
print(x)  # []
```

You can get the behavior of the second example in Python if you pass a copy of the object. For lists, you use `[:]`.

```
# Pretend this is Pascal code.
x = []
def foo_adder(y):
    y.append('foo')
foo_adder(x[:])
print(x)  # []
```

For your second question about how the caller might not see the change, let's take that same `foo_adder` function and change it a little so that it doesn't modify the object, but instead replaces it.

```
x = []
def foo_adder(y):
    y = y + ['foo']
foo_adder(x)
print(x)  # []
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't know what you're talking about. ;) (Thanks for pointing that out).

Answer (score 3):

> What would be an example of how exactly the caller will see a change?

```
>>> def modify(x):
...     x.append(1)
...
>>> seq = []
>>> print(seq)
[]
>>> modify(seq)
>>> print(seq)
[1]
```

> Or how could it be (not in Python but in general) that the caller doesn't see the change?

Hypothetically, a language could exist where a deep copy of `seq` is created and assigned to `x`, and any change made to `x` has no effect on `seq`, in which case `print(seq)` would display `[]` both times. But this isn't what happens in Python.

---

Edit: note that assigning a new value to an old variable name typically doesn't count as "modification".

```
>>> def f(x):
...     x = x + 1
...
>>> y = 23
>>> f(y)
>>> print(y)
23
```

Comment: Local assignments aren't visible outside their current scope even if you're assigning to an identifier that currently contains a mutable object. Suppose the function did `x = x + [1]`. Then `z = []; f(z); print(z)` would print `[]` even though lists are mutable.